# TextBox ignores "Space" key input. Why?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm developing an app for Windows Phone 7 and I faced quite a strange problem with the standard TextBox: I cannot type "Space". All other keys work just fine but the "Space" key is simply ignored with no errors popping up.

I populate the textbox dynamically. Here's the code responsible for this:

```
var newComment = new TextBox()
{
    Width = 378,
    MaxLength = 128,
    AcceptsReturn = true,
    /*Tag = ... ,*/
    /*Style = ... ,*/
    /*BorderBrush = ... ,*/
    Margin = new Thickness(-12, 0, 0, 0)
};

newComment.InputScope = new InputScope();
newComment.InputScope.Names.Add(new InputScopeName() { NameValue = InputScopeNameValue.Text });

newComment.KeyDown += (sender, args) =>
{
    if (args.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Enter)
    {
        args.Handled = true;
        /* ... */
    }
};

container.Items.Add(newComment);
```

I commented out some stuff that (I think) is irrelevant. The "container" is an instance of ListBox.

When I put a breakpoint inside the "KeyDown" event handler and press "Space", the `args.Key` is "Unknown" (`args.PlatformKeyCode` is "160"). I have textboxes in other places of my app (not dynamic though) and they work just fine.

Tested on emulator as well as on the device (I have HTC Mozart if this makes any difference). Developing for Mango.

Comment: If you're going to use Text as the input scope, why do you need to specify this? Isn't this the standard one when you create a textbox?

Comment: The standard one is "Default" which doesn't have auto-completion.

Comment: I made a test project with your code now, and it worked perfectly. It does not ignore the space key, nor does it give me unknown in the .KeyDown event-handler e.Key field (it says Space). The problem must be elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Screenshot: http://tinypic.com/r/nf98x/6

Comment: @KrisSelbekk I should have done this quick test by myself before crying loud on SO. I have resolved my issue (the my answer). Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: No biggie. Enjoy your day :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that the problem was caused because of the `TextBox` being inside a `Button` (because I needed to be able to tap on the whole "thing"). Placing it outside of the `Button` fixed the issue.

Comment: If you need to tap on whole "thing" like you said use `Padding` property of `TextBox`

Comment: @harry180 I'm sorry if I wasn't clear enough, but there are other controls apart from `TextBox` (I have like, a publication record with the name, date and a list of comments). This is what I meant by saying "the whole thing".